# Programming to fill our system's L1 or L2 cache

Tags: c, caching, assembly

How we can systematically write code to load data into our L1 or L2 cache?

I am specifically trying to target filling the the L1 I cache of my system for some higher analysis.
Any suggestions will do - with respect to writing assembly code or simple C programming. Related articles on this topic will be even more helpful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444148/is-there-a-way-to-force-a-variable-to-be-stored-in-the-cache-in-c

Answer (score 3):

A cache stores recently-accessed data. To fill the cache, just access the data. Or in this case, instructions. Fill a block of memory with no-op instructions (and a looping branch instruction at the end) and jump to it.

The tricky part is keeping data in there once it's loaded. You can't access anything outside the 32K (or whatever) data set as long as your benchmark is running.

I can't imagine what you get from artificially filling a cache and then keeping it filled with the same data set, but there you go.

Comment: is it possible to check whether the L1 I cache is full or not?? some sort of memory statistics, associated with MY running of test.asm

(assume my test.asm has enough nop instructions to fill the 32K I cache and alo assume no looping is done here)

Comment: This would assume a fully associative cache (they almost never are, even when advertised the CPUs are cheating) and a pure LRU replacement policy (they almost never are) and no split I/D caches (which many CPUs still have today) and an operating system that doesn't do anything while the benchmark is running (OSes always run at the most inconvenient time).

Answer (score 2):

You will need to find out the cache associativity of your CPU and the replacement policy. I can't think of a general solution to this problem that would work on all the CPUs I've worked with. Even caches advertised as fully associative with an LRU replacement policy aren't exactly that in reality and it can be very hard to figure out a pattern of memory access that completely fills the cache.

If you want this for some very specific benchmark (which is a bad idea for other reasons), I'd recommend you trying to figure out how to flush the cache instead. That is actually doable.

Comment: (I am using ubuntu) - the lscpu instruction gives me exactly my split cache arrangement and size allocation. Also checking my system device settings (ie by - cd /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index0) will give me all details related to the cache structure (level, coherancy and associativity)

Comment: how do you suggest working around this - assuming that i know these features about my cache

Comment: Well, given the associativity, cache line since, cache size and the replacement policy it can sometimes (but not always) be possible to figure out an access pattern to fill up the cache. [Here's a decent article talking about caches](http://lwn.net/Articles/252125/). But notice that most caches are physical and you're most likely operating in virtual memory. The OS won't give you nicely aligned memory. It's a better bet to figure out how to flush the cache since that's achievable on most systems and puts the cache in a known state.

Comment: The real question is though: what problem are you trying to solve? Keeping a cache in a known state during a benchmark while running on top of an operating system is very hard.

Comment: My objective is to get gain memory statistics (avg. memory access time for my L1 I cache) - for that i wish to fill my cache completely and compute the statistics using the rdtsc instruction

Answer (score 1):

I just last week performed this task for ECC filling of an l1 and l2 cache.

Basically if you have a 64Kbyte cache, for example, total (x number of ways, y number of cache lines, etc) for the data just access that much data linearly through the cache (might need an mmu on to enable caching) start on some 64Kbyte boundary and read 64Kbytes worth of data ideally in cache line sized reads (or multiples) if possible.  For icache you need that many bytes worth of instructions (nops or add reg+1 or something), remember there is probably a pre-fetch at the end so you might have to back off the final return a few instructions so that the prefetch takes you all the way to the end (might take some practice and if you dont have visibility into the logic (a chip sim) then you might not figure it out.

you can use the mmu or other games your logic might have to reduce the amount of memory required, for example if you have an mmu with an entry size that covers say 4Kb, then you could fill 4Kb of real memory with data, then use 16 different mmu entries (with 16 different virtual addresses) and for each of the 16 read through the 4K.  Of course that is if your cache is on the virtual address side of the mmu.

overall it is kind of an ugly thing to do, if your mmu prevents instruction caching, you could put the code performing the test in a non-cached space so that it doesnt mess with the icache and only instructions used to fill the cache are in a cached address space.

Good luck...